# HTTP to HTTPS 301 Redirection Code is Not Working, It says Too many redirects

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I am using Bluehost for one of my websites. Recently, Recently, i have moved my site from HTTP to HTTPS . 
After that, I have used So may different code including the below code to force HTTPS all over my website.

```
# SSL Rewrite
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

After using this post, when I check redirection on **redirect-checker** available on online, I get following messages.

> But it is not working. Too many redirects. Please try to reduce your
>   number of redirects for http://www.example.com. You use 19 Redirects.
>   Ideally, you should not use more than 3 Redirects in a redirect chain.
>   More than three redirections will produce unnecessary load on your
>   server and reduce speed, which ends up in bad user experience.

And If you want to access my website **from a browser**, I get warning as such:

> The www.example.com page isn’t working. www.example.com redirected you
>   too many times.

I think some redirection loop was creating such problem.

However,

My web site Status Right Now: Without using any code on htaccess

> 1. https//www.example.com is working just fine. returning 200 OK. 200 OK2
> 2. https//example.com  is now 301 redirected to https//www.example.com (So, i think it is also just fine)

The problem is:

> 3. http//example.com  is now 301 redirected to http//www.example.com
> 4. http//www. example.com  is returning 200 OK.

To solve problem 3, I included Below code on my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

After that I found that:

> http//example.com  is now 301 redirected to https//www.example.com

So the problem is solved for:

```
http//example.com
https//example.com
https//www.example.com
```

Now I just need some code to redirect 301 only:

> http//www.example.com TO https//www.example.com`

Can anybody help me here?

And I am sorry if I explain my problem in a wired way... :D. The matter is I am not an expert guy on this. Hope you all will understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If not www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# rewrite to https and www
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# If not HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But it did not work! 

> First

 it 301 redirects from `http://www.example.com **TO** https://www.example.com`. 

after that, it 

 keeps redirecting

 the `https://www.example.com **TO** https://www.example.com` again and again around 20 times.