# .htaccess http to https causes too many redirects error

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

First of all I'd like to say that I've re-read a lot of articles on this topic but my problem persists.

I have a Yii2-based project using advanced template, but I believe the problem doesn't apply to framework.

My .htaccess files is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # www to none www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.fashion-megapolis.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fashion-megapolis.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  # Force SSL
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

My www to none www rules works great. If I remove a force ssl part - my site works as expected, but whithout HTTPS of course.

So, these rules are very common and I tried lots of variations but get a "too many redirects" error all the time.

Thank you in advance

Comment: For better understanding, I have these redirects:
http://fashion-megapolis.com => https://fashion-megapolis.com/ => 
https://fashion-megapolis.com/ => https://fashion-megapolis.com/ etc...

As for me it looks like the "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off" condition is ALWAYS false

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532560/http-to-https-301-redirection-code-is-not-working-it-says-too-many-redirects/42534238#42534238